# How to delete a specific element from xml file

Tags: php, xml

I want to delete:

```
<newWord>
    <Heb>צהוב</Heb>
    <Eng>yellow</Eng>
 </newWord>
```

from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
  <newWord>
    <Heb>מילה ראשונה</Heb>
    <Eng>first word</Eng>
  </newWord>
  <newWord>
    <Heb>צהוב</Heb>
    <Eng>yellow</Eng>
  </newWord>
</xml>
```

so the output will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xml>
      <newWord>
        <Heb>מילה ראשונה</Heb>
        <Eng>first word</Eng>
      </newWord>
    </xml>
```

I try to find the tag `<newWord>` and after this to go to child of it  `<Eng>yellow</Eng>`
and if i found it by `$searchString = 'yellow';` I should need to go to parrent of it and delete the element `<newWord>`.

I try to do it by the following code but I do not know ho to go to child of the  `<newWord>`. many thx for helping.

this my code:

```
<?php 
$del=true;
        if ($del==TRUE){
                $searchString = 'yellow';
                header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
                $xml = simplexml_load_file('./Dictionary_user.xml');



                foreach($xml->children() as $child){
                  if($child->getName() == "newWord") {
                      if($searchString == $child['Eng']) {
                        $dom->parentNode->removeChild($xml);
                    } else {
                        echo('no match found resualt');
                    }
                  }
                }

                $dom = new DOMDocument; 
                $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
                $dom->formatOutput = true;
                $dom->load('Dictionary_user.xml');

                $dom->save("Dictionary_user.xml");
                $dom->saveXML();
                header('Location: http://127.0.0.1/www/www1/ajax/ajax4/workwell/popus1.html');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$searchString = 'yellow';
$xml = simplexml_load_file('./Dictionary_user.xml');

foreach($xml->children() as $child){    
  if($child->getName() == "newWord") {
    if($child->Eng == $searchString){
        $dom = dom_import_simplexml($child);
        $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
    }
  }
}

echo $xml->asXML();
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line

```
if($searchString == $child['Eng']) {
```

You're trying to compare the body of the child node, but it doesn't convert to a string automatically.  It's still a `SimpleXMLElement object`, so the comparison fails.

Try explicitly casting it to a string to get the body of the tag.

```
if($searchString == (string)$child['Eng']) {
```